# Uncaught TypeError: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined при запуске .exe файла. (РЕШЕНИЕ-РАБОТАТЬ В VS И НЕ ПАРИТСЯ)

Tags: c++, atom

Разрядность 64-бит. Добавлял в PATH (и в пользовательские и в системные) SDL2, mingw. Сгенерировалось всё нормально, но вот с самим файлом game.exe всё сложно. При простом открытии ошибка и абракадабра в редакторе, при опции "*Compile and Run*" или "*Compile and Debug*" просто ошибка. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

**Вообще, если честно когда работал с Visual Studio никаких ошибок и проблем не было.  В Atom'e же приходится неделями бороться с ошибками и сидеть на форумах (это касается только проектов на c++). Но переходить обратно не хочется, Atom быстрее и приятнее.**

main.cpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
build:
    g++ -Wfatal-errors -std=c++2a $(wildcard *.cpp) -I"C:\libsdl\include" -L"C:\libsdl\lib" -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o game.exe
```

[image: Собственно ошибка]

Ошибка (Stack Trace)

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:107:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:406:3)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:542:16)
    at compile (C:\Users\Arvil\.atom\packages\gpp-compiler\index.js:274:31)
    at HTMLLIElement.treeCompile (C:\Users\Arvil\.atom\packages\gpp-compiler\index.js:251:3)
    at CommandRegistry.handleCommandEvent (C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.53.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:350265)
    at CommandRegistry.dispatch (C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.53.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:348740)
    at AtomEnvironment.dispatchContextMenuCommand (C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.53.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:1:767132)
    at EventEmitter.t (C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.53.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:1:775138)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at Object.onMessage (C:\Users\Arvil\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.53.0\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js:42:16)
```

Comment: Ошибка не в плюсах, это какой-то баг в самом атоме. И судя по сообщению, он уже зарепорчен, и если нажать на кнопку, можно его посмотреть.

Comment: Там в обсуждениях 8 комментов, из них нормального решения нет.

Comment: Скиньте ссылку что ли. Если там ничего интересного нет, то только ждать, пока пофиксят.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat    https://github.com/kriscross07/atom-gpp-compiler/issues/336

Comment: Ну там же пишут, выбрать язык `C++` вместо `C++14`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat у меня такой проблемы нет. В grammar отображается c++

Comment: Ну тогда ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну тогда visual studio) спасибо что пытались помочь

Comment: Попробуйте visual studio code, он легче чем обычный vs, однако не такой умный, но плагинами можно много что подкрутить

Comment: понял, попробую, спасибо

Comment: "*Atom быстрее и приятнее*" - что? это же браузерный редактор